# Код инcтрументирования объектов cookie стека обнаружил переполнение буфера

Tags: c++, массивы, память

Есть класс Board, в private создаю двумерный массив указателей:

```
private:
Figure *board_m[8][8];
```

Потом в конструкторе создаю новые экземпляры классов и заношу в массив:

```
Board() {
    cout << "Chess start" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            board_m[i][j] =  new Figure;
        }
    }
}
```

В самом конце в деструкторе я удаляю все созданные ранее экземпляры:

```
~Board() {
    cout<< "Goodbye" <<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            delete board_m[i][j];
        }
    }

}
```

Но к концу программы мне в Visual Studio выдает вот такое окно:
[image: Код инcтрументирования объектов cookie стека обнаружил переполнение буфера]
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

И как вы представляете себе

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        board_m[i][j] =  new Figure;
    }
}
```

при `i==8` или `j == 8`, если `board_m` объявлен как массив 8x8? Вы пишете за пределы выделенной массиву памяти, вот и портите стек...

Интересно, что при удалении вы работаете совершенно верно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        delete board_m[i][j];
    }
}
```

Вот так же поступайте и при выделении памяти...

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сам не заметил:)